# How to approach branch cut question that involves infinitesmal stuff?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, branch-cuts, branch-points

anybody have any idea how to approach part b) of the  branch cut question like the one below???
[image]

Comment: I ***believe*** that they are asking you to find $$\lim_{u\searrow 0}f(t+iu),$$ but they're asking it in a ridiculous way.